# WordPress: Styling taxonomy slug page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom `taxonomy` called `Topics`.

`Topics` currently has three categories:

[image]

Note the count of posts for each category above.

When a user goes to a topic page, i.e. `/topics/news`, I want to show all posts related to `news` neatly, so looking to write custom markup.

To do this, I have come across [taxonomy templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/), but getting weird results.

For starters, I'm on /`topics/news`. From the above image, you can see `News` has 2 posts.

Here is my `taxonomy-topics.php` file:

```html
<?php get_header();

  if ( have_posts() ){
    while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_title();
    }
  }

get_footer(); ?>
```

Just trying to show the title of the `news` posts at the moment. However, it is looping through and printing the title for one post several times. Seems like there's an infinite loop happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call [`the_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/) so that the post index is moved to the next one in the posts array in the main query (i.e. the `$wp_query` global):

```php
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); // call this or you'll be stuck in an infinite loop! :)
    the_title();
}
```